# Сохранить набор строк Datagridview локально на компьютере пользователя

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

Подскажите пожалуйста советом по c# winforms vs2010. По кнопке с формы1 открывается форма2, в которой расположен Datagridview. При открытии формы2 в этот Datagridview кодом загружаются три столбца с данными из файла mdb. Далее пользователь выбирает нужную строку (строки) из Datagridview и нажимая кнопку на форме2 добавляет их в ListBox на форму1.

Как можно сделать следующее: пользователь открыл форму2, выбрал (по одной строке) в Datagridview нужные строки и создал группу из этих данных, как бы выборку под своим именем. И чтобы у каждого пользователя программы при открытии формы2 отображались свои ранее сохраненные выборки.

Это нужно для того, чтобы пользователь каждый раз не выбирал нужные строки из Datagridview для добавления их в ListBox, а мог определить и сохранить свой набор строк.

Comment: эти данные нужно хранить в базе (чтобы при закрытии программы сохранить). Например добавили таблицу и в нее записали id пользователя и номер выделенной строки (несколько записей в таблицу с пользователем). Потом при загрузке из mdb выделить их

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема еще в том, что при запуске формы2 набор данных в Datagridview может меняться (если изменен файл mdb). Поэтому хотелось бы выгружать выбранные строки из Datagridview в типа "настройки" программы? (с помощью, например, 2-х кнопок "создать выборку" и "удалить выборку").

Comment: дак это не важно изменен файл или нет. в Datagridview загружаете весь файл, просто выбранными данные остаются те же, что и были (в базе одна таблица это Ваши данные, а вторая - это выбранные строки у пользователя.

Comment: если нужно хранить данные в настройках программы, то можно сделать xml файл и в него записывать выбранные строки. Для этого создаете класс и потом сереализация/десереализация xml

Comment: Спасибо большое!